# magento2 cron not reindex

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I have created a crontab with this command in my Ubuntu Server and Plesk 12.5 :

```
MAILTO=""
SHELL="/bin/bash"
*/1 *   *   *   *   php -c -f /var/www/vhosts/system/domainname.com/etc/php.ini /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/bin/magento cron:run > /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/var/log/magento.cron.log&
MAILTO=""
SHELL="/bin/bash"
*/1 *   *   *   *   php -c -f /var/www/vhosts/system/domainname.com/etc/php.ini /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/update/cron.php > /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/var/log/update.cron.log&
MAILTO=""
SHELL="/bin/bash"
*/1 *   *   *   *   php -c -f /var/www/vhosts/system/domainname.com/etc/php.ini /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/bin/magento setup:cron:run > /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

When run it creates three files (magento.cron.log; update.cron.log; setup.cron.log). And three files cotains the same text:

> ; ATTENTION! ;  ; DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED
>   AUTOMATICALLY, ; SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE
>   FILE IS GENERATED.
>
> [PHP] soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5 cli_server.color = On
>   mysql.allow_persistent = On mysqli.max_persistent = -1
>   mysql.connect_timeout = 60 session.use_only_cookies = 1
>   register_argc_argv = Off mssql.min_error_severity = 10 open_basedir =
>   "/var/www/vhosts/mydomainname.com/:/tmp/" session.name = PHPSESSID
>   mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On session.hash_function = 0
>   session.gc_probability = 0 log_errors_max_len = 1024
>   mssql.secure_connection = Off pgsql.max_links = -1 variables_order =
>   "GPCS" ldap.max_links = -1 sybct.allow_persistent = On max_input_time
>   = 60 odbc.max_links = -1 session.save_handler = files session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5" mysqli.cache_size = 2000
>   pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off error_reporting = E_ALL &
>   ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT auto_prepend_file = 
>   sybct.min_client_severity = 10 pgsql.max_persistent = -1
>   auto_globals_jit = On soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400 allow_url_fopen = On
>   zend.enable_gc = On mysqli.allow_persistent = On tidy.clean_output =
>   Off display_startup_errors = Off user_dir =  session.cookie_lifetime =
>   0 mysqli.max_links = -1 default_socket_timeout = 60
>   session.serialize_handler = php session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
>   unserialize_callback_func =  pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
>   default_mimetype = "text/html" session.cache_expire = 180
>   max_execution_time = 30 mail.add_x_header = On upload_max_filesize =
>   2M ibase.max_links = -1 zlib.output_compression = Off
>   ignore_repeated_errors = Off odbc.max_persistent = -1 file_uploads =
>   On ibase.max_persistent = -1 mysqli.reconnect = Off
>   mssql.allow_persistent = On mysql.max_persistent = -1 mssql.max_links
>   = -1 session.use_trans_sid = 0 mysql.default_socket =  always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 mysql.max_links = -1
>   odbc.defaultbinmode = 1 sybct.max_persistent = -1 output_buffering =
>   4096 ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S" doc_root =  log_errors = On
>   mysql.default_host =  default_charset = "UTF-8" request_order = "GP"
>   display_errors = Off mysqli.default_socket =  mysqli.default_pw = 
>   html_errors = On mssql.compatibility_mode = Off ibase.allow_persistent
>   = 1 sybct.min_server_severity = 10 mysql.allow_local_infile = On post_max_size = 8M asp_tags = Off memory_limit = 512M short_open_tag =
>   Off SMTP = localhost precision = 14 session.use_strict_mode = 0
>   session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440 allow_url_include = Off
>   mysqli.default_host =  mysqli.default_user =  session.referer_check = 
>   pgsql.log_notice = 0 mysql.default_port =  pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
>   mysql.trace_mode = Off ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
>   engine = On odbc.allow_persistent = On ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
>   track_errors = Off max_file_uploads = 20 pgsql.allow_persistent = On
>   session.auto_start = 0 auto_append_file =  disable_classes = 
>   pdo_mysql.default_socket =  mysql.default_password = 
>   url_rewriter.tags =
>   "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry" smtp_port = 25
>   sql.safe_mode = Off session.cookie_path = / expose_php = On
>   report_memleaks = On session.gc_divisor = 1000 mssql.max_persistent =
>   -1 serialize_precision = 17 odbc.check_persistent = On sybct.max_links = -1 mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off session.cookie_domain =  session.cookie_httponly =  session.cache_limiter = nocache enable_dl =
>   Off mysqli.default_port = 3306 disable_functions =  odbc.defaultlrl =
>   4096 soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1 soap.wsdl_cache_dir = "/tmp"
>   mssql.min_message_severity = 10 session.use_cookies = 1
>   mysql.default_user =  mysql.cache_size = 2000 implicit_flush = Off
>   ignore_repeated_source = Off bcmath.scale = 0

But when I enter magenta manager keeps giving the message "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."

I do not understand. What Is It that is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gotten the [flags for php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) wrong. It should be

```
*/1 *   *   *   *   php -c /var/www/vhosts/system/domainname.com/etc/php.ini -f /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/bin/magento cron:run > /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/store/var/log/magento.cron.log&
```

Also provide full path to php, which can be figured out with `which php` command.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But if I use with php and put /usr/bin/php then in the magenta.cron.log the content is "Autoload error: glob() returned error while searching in '/var/www/vhosts/midomain.com/httpdocs/store/app/code/*/*/cli_commands.php'"

Comment: I change /usr/bin/php for /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php and work!